# Cordova "Local Notifications" plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, local

Does anyone know where I can get the Cordova 3.x.x compatible "Local Notifications" plugin for Android?

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin (iOS/Android/WP8). For Cordova 3+

**https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications**

Callbacks, badges, sound, repeat and cancel are **working great**.

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091630/cordova-android-local-notification-status